# How do I remove webapps completely?

Tags: webapps

I'd like to be able to remove webapps from my system, I don't want any of the packages associated with it. But trying to remove it I am told there are several other packages that require it. Please change this, I don't like the idea of webapps and I want it gone.

Comment: And what is it that gets removed along with web apps?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the packages `unity-chromium-extension` and `xul-ext-websites-integration`.

Also remove *Unity WebApps Chromium extension* from Chromium browser and *Unity Website integration* add-on from Firefox browser.